# Handling listbox in C# visual Studio with if statement

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have three options in my listbox that which choosing each item it will open a different page. but my current code is not opening any of the pages.

```
private void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String choice= listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    switch (choice)
    {
        case "Canada":
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
                frm2.Show();
                break;
            }

        case "United States":
            {
                Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                frm3.Show();
                break;
            }

        case "Mexico":
            {
                Form4 frm4 = new Form4();
                frm4.Show();
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to diagnose the problem you're having.  The code you've posted here looks fine.

Comment: That's why I don't know what is the problem. I do not get any error but it doesn't do the commands

Comment: Do these two things: Verify that go_Button_Click() is actually being called by putting a break on the String choice line. If it does break there...check the value of choice and you should have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

(1) Switch never matches? Use `switch (choice.ToUpper())` then change your cases to be all uppercase like `case "CANADA"`.  Or maybe there are other characters in the listbox entry that you haven't taken into account?

(2) The handler is not "wired up"?  Click on the "goButton" control to select it.  In the Properties Pane (bottom right by default), click on the "Lightning Bolt" icon to see the events listed for that control.  Find the "Click" entry and make sure it has "goButton_Click" listed in there.  If it doesn't, click on the dropdown arrow to the right of that entry and change it.